# TensorRT and CuDNN for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, tensorflow, dynamic-linking

How can I install these libraries/packages in Ubuntu 20.04?

```
2020-07-21 19:52:02.656660: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-07-21 19:52:02.656748: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-07-21 19:52:02.656756: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
```

I have the following information:

```
$ nvcc -V
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243

$ nvidia-smi
Tue Jul 21 20:05:46 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.05    Driver Version: 450.51.05    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2070    On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8     8W /  N/A |    967MiB /  7982MiB |     12%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1384      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                699MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1809      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              256MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4590      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4688      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      5057      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal


$ uname -a
Linux mona 5.4.0-40-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 23 00:01:04 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Check carefully the tensorflow version you are using, and its requirements for CUDA -- typically it will require an earlier version of CUDA than the latest.